# Why would a consistent number of visitors be missing User-Agent headers?

Tags: http, mobile, user-agent

We recently deployed a mobile version of our site, and part of that deployment included a User-Agent check to determine which version to deliver to the end user.

Every minute or so since we released, we've had an Elmah error from an exception that was thrown when a User-Agent was blank.

We've already fixed the issue in production, but I'm curious as to why a consistent (but very small) percentage of our traffic might not have User-Agent defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple guess, but it *could* come from bots.

There's an amazing number of bots (search engines, botnets, and others) that constantly scan websites and servers for vulnerabilities, passwords and such. Sometimes they have a known User-Agent, sometimes not.

You could use a CDN service like [CloudFlare](http://www.cloudflare.com) to get an idea of how many of those requests come from robots (no, I don't work for that company - but using their services made me realize how much the web is polluted by bots, the stats are scary).

Comment: Are there any other explanations? I've seen similar circumstances as the question asker, except they are certainly not bots because they are forwarded from one of our 3rd party websites with valid information mapping to our system (as in customer information etc. that a bot could not know).